# Why does it print out "abracadabra" and not "Timmy"?

Tags: c++, exception

This code throws an exception when I enter "Timmy" as the name. I'm really not sure of the mechanism but why does it print out "abracadabra" and not "Timmy". One thing I'm sure of though is that there is no magic going on here!

This is the short code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

string enterName();
void   checkName(string);


int main()
{
  string someName = "abracadabra";

  try {
    someName = enterName();
  }
  catch(const char* error) {
    cout << "main function says: "<<error <<endl;
  }

  cout << "Name: "<<someName<<endl;

  return 0;
}

string enterName()
{
  string s;

  cout<<"Enter a name: ";
  cin >> s;
  cout<<endl;

  try {
    checkName(s);
  }
  catch(const char* err) {
    cout << "middle man says: "<<err <<endl;
    throw "rtetfrer";
  }

  return s;
}

void checkName(string name)
{
  if (name == "Timmy")
    throw "Help, Timmy's been kidnapped by a giant squid!";
}
```

Comment: You threw an exception past the assignment.

Comment: I'd upvote the question if you'd come up with a better title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are throwing an exception, so the function never returns:

```
void checkName(string name)
{
  if (name == "Timmy")
    //This throws an exception, so the function exits immediately
    throw "Help, Timmy's been kidnapped by a giant squid!";
}
```

That exception is caught here:

```
  try {
    checkName(s);
  }
  catch(const char* err) {
    //This will be the exception that timmy is caught
    cout << "middle man says: "<<err <<endl;

    //This will throw an exception and immediately exit the function
    throw "rtetfrer";
  }

  //This will never be called
  return s;
```

And the new exception will be caught here:

```
catch(const char* error) {
    cout << "main function says: "<<error <<endl;
  }
```

But since `checkName` never returned a value, `somename` will still be magic

Answer (score 1):

`enterName();` throws an exception **before** the assignment to `someName` is made. Hence `someName` retains its original value.

(In a little more detail: `enterName()` calls `checkName()`. `checkName()` throws an exception `since` name is "Timmy". `enterName()` throws "rtetfrer". Why not verify with your debugger?)

Answer (score 0):

In order to assign a value to `someName`, `c++` must first evaluate the expression on the left side. That is the result of the function `enterName`. Now during the execution of this function an exception is thrown. When this happens the execution jumps right to the catch clause(skipping the return clause of the function and then the assignment of `someName` to this return value), thus you never assign a different value to `someName`.

Use a debugger to follow the execution flow in an easier manner.